# Regex to match string which has words followed by whitespace then digits dot or hyphen and words followed by space and then (some info)

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which has the following format:
`name category (more info)`

eg: `Foo Bar-8.io 5.61.0-rc-1 (data)`

I need a regex which basically filters out strings conforming to the above format.

name can be alpha numeric with spaces, `-` and `.`

category can start with digit followed by word including dot or hyphen

data can be anything `.*` enclosed in `()`

I have tried this: `^[\w\s]+.*\s.*\(.*\)$` but doesnot seems to cover the above pattern.

Comment: Try `^(\w+(?:[\s.-]\w+)*?)\s+(\d[\w.-]*)\s+\(([^()]*)\)$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/T4vAbR/1).

Comment: Without spaces allowed in the category, maybe just a few greedy groups could work like [`^(.*) (.*) \((.*)\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/usoAZq/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
^(.*)\s+(\S+)\s+\((.*)\)$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/kuIUpe/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```